# Git rebase local vs git pull --rebase origin

Tags: git, version-control, git-rebase, branching-and-merging

I have a local (never pushed to a remote) feature branch ***F1*** made from ***master*** with a few commits. I don't seem to understand a difference between these two actions (***F1*** is the current branch):

```
git fetch origin
git rebase master
```

and

```
git pull --rebase origin master
```

My expectation is that they should be equivalent but they aren't - different results are produced.

What's wrong with my thinking?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**1.** `git fetch origin` and `git rebase master` will apply changes from `F1` to local `master` branch. Assume your commit history looks like below at first (the remote `master` branch has commit `J` in remote):

```
A---B---C---D---E    master
         \
          F---G---H  F1
```

When you execute `git fetch origin` and `git rebase master`, even though `origin/master` points to `J`, it will only rebase `F1` branch on the top of local `master` branch (commit `E` as the graph):

```
A---B---C---D---E(master)---J origin/master
                 \
                  F---G---H    F1
```

**2.** The command `git pull --rebase origin master` will pull changes from remote `master` branch at first, then rebase current branch `F1` on the top of it:

```
A---B---C---D---E---J      master,origin/master 
                     \
                      F---G---H  F1
```

In a word, if local `master` branch is sync with remote `master` branch, these two ways have the same result (rebase `F1` branch on the top of master branch). If remote `master` branch has new commit(s) which is(are) not exist on local `master` branch, the results are different (one rebases on local `master` branch, the other rebase on `origin/master` branch).

Comment: Fantastic explanation.  I'd also suggest adding --autostash to automatically stash and pop local changes during this process.  In total: `git pull --rebase --autostash origin master`

Answer (score -2):

```
git fetch origin
```

only download remote files from a remote repository into your local branch.

```
git rebase master
```

takes the whole branch (the commits that are in your branch), and put on the top of your local repository. It changes the history of your project.

```
git pull --rebase origin master
```

git pull by default, performs a merge, but you can force it with a rebase option.

check this [link](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/merging-vs-rebasing)